# Laravel valet share production domain

Tags: laravel, server, host, valet

Is it possible to serve my production domain through Laravel valet service??
I have my domain which I have purchased but I want to share my website through valet.

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet) is pretty much exclusively for local development and not recommended to run production code. It's essentially a lightweight shortcut to allow you to start developing in Laravel quickly. It is also exclusively maintained for a Mac - I mention this as most production websites are run on a Linux or Windows environment, and support for running on a Mac would be relatively small. (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Server-Operating-System-market-share)

Off the top of my head, this is also not a good idea as Valet proxies all folders that you run `valet park` to `http://[folder_name].test` URLs, which could theoretically open up security holes if you accidentally moved something in your local development environment into the parked folder. Essentially, it opens you up to a bunch of security issues, that just being one of the first ones.

I know it's tempting to want to just publish a site as everything "just works" on your local environment, but I would highly recommend finding a dedicated host for your website running in production. There are a plethora of hosting packages allowing you to run your Laravel application safely and cheaply.

Answer (score -1):

Shared hosting is alot easier then Valet. I spent a good 4 hours trying to get valet working on my mac cause I had about. 5 versions of PHP. If you use Valet on a production server then you going to have to pay more for a more dedicated server that will allow you to install the software. And your getting a less productive enviroment. Your basically paying more for less quality. A shared hosting site will atleast provide support to fix any server issues non related to your web app and your paying less.